# Can't see created folder in teamdrive root

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm creating a folder inside teamdrive root with google-drive-sdk and it works but with some delay after API call finished. If I try to query root folder with the name of newly created folder right after creation - I get an empty array. But if I do the same after couple of seconds I see the new item.

```
$file = $service->files->create(
    $folder,
    [
        "supportsTeamDrives" => true
    ]
);
printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

I see the folder ID

```
$params = [
    "q" => "'{$teamDriveId}' in parents and trashed = false and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name ='$path'",
    "pageSize" => 1,
    "corpora"               => "teamDrive",
    "includeTeamDriveItems" => true,
    "supportsTeamDrives"    => true,
    "teamDriveId"           => $teamDriveId
];

$files = $service->files->listFiles($params);
$list = $files->getFiles();

var_dump($list);
```

Empty array

But if I do 'sleep(3)' before query - an array is not empty and contains new folder.

I didn't find any information about this delay in documentation. What is it and is there a way to get the result without delays?

Answer (score 0):

While I can't speak to the internals of the Drive API, I can imagine that any delay between creating the folder, and the folder being queryable from [`Files.list()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list), is due to internal indexing and data propagation for Team Drives, since they are different than the regular Drive files.

Note that such an use case -- *I create this file then immediately need to find it* -- is avoidable - the act of [creating the file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create#response) has a return value that includes the direct handle to the file created.

> **Response**
>   If successful, this method returns a Files resource in the response body.

Comment: It's clear that they do some internal indexing. But why they do it asynchronously? Because from my point of view within this delay data is not consistent. And why there is no any information about such indexing in documentation?

Comment: @limion I don't work at Google so I couldn't tell you why they don't prominently give public information about those implementation specifics. It's possible there are white papers or similar developer reference documents on the underlying protocols which have more information. As for why the indexing is async: so they can provide a faster response that gives you what you need to use the file reference.